# Does gitlab API have a rate limit

Tags: api, gitlab

github has a rate limit of 5000/hour for OAuth client, but I can't find the same information from **gitlab** (apart from 6/minute for creating new users and resetting password), does it mean there's no limit?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is [no longer "no"](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1966#note_20066664), at least on gitlab.com:

> We enabled capacity limiting on GitLab.com to reduce impact of GitLab Runners on stability of GitLab.

Now each API response has the following headers:

```
RateLimit-Limit: 600
RateLimit-Observed: 12
RateLimit-Remaining: 588
```

From [this issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-cookbooks/gitlab-haproxy/merge_requests/49), it looks like the limit is 10 requests per second per IP address.

Answer (score 1):

For self-managed deploys the rate limits are configurable. For GitLab.com specific rate limits see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/index.html#gitlabcom-specific-rate-limits).

Answer (score 0):

As of today (September 2016), the answer is no.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like GitLab has now (December 2019) documented their rate limits.

gitlab.com-specific rate limits are documented here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/gitlab_com/index.html#gitlabcom-specific-rate-limits

TL;DR: 10 requests per second per IP address (as @Maxim mentioned)

And I believe this is for enterprise rate limiting: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/security/rate_limits.html