# How can I install Passport on Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport

Im trying to install passport on my Laravel 9 project, but I get that error
`Could not fetch https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/stella-maris%2Fclock/repository/archive.zip?sha=8a0a967896df4c63417385dc69328a0aec84d9cf, enter your gitlab.com credentials to go over the API rate limit` I tryed to access this url but is blocked for me. How can I solve it.

Comment: I'm usin composer

Comment: check this post i think is duplicated . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38478806/does-gitlab-api-have-a-rate-limit

Answer (score 1):

This policy has been active at Github a long time regrettably. It is documented [here](https://developer.github.com/v3/rate_limit/) and you can see your current status at https://api.github.com/rate_limit in the core section

Also see https://developer.github.com/v3/#rate-limiting:

There is nothing Composer can do to circumvent that, hence why it throws the verbose error:

```
Create a GitHub OAuth token to go over the API rate limit
```

You can do this at https://github.com/settings/tokens, and it needs to be done only once per installation as Composer remembers the token for subsequent requests.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I solve it by connecting myself through a proxy server.